# rails 4: Rails.env is different from ENV["RAILS_ENV"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set in my `config/environment.rb` file `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "production"` in order to run my server on my machine (using `rails server`) and get the production behavior. I have a lot of lines in my code that check if `Rails.env.production?` to assign a different functionality for some of the app components. 
My problem is that when I check the environment in one of my controller I get different results for `Rails.env` and `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`. The first will show "development" while the second will be "production".

Shouldn't both of the methods return the same value?

Answer (score 1):

By the time config/environment.rb is evaluated you're just modifying the ENV hash. If you want to run your app in production set the RAILS_ENV environment variable in the shell you use to run rails.

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

Answer (score 1):

To run your rails server in production mode run :

```
rails s -e production
```

And to answer your actual question :

`Rails.env` uses `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` internally, see :
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d25fe31c40928712b5e08fe0afb567c3bc88eddf/railties/lib/rails.rb#L59-L61

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

but `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` which is actually not set till now, so the option that is passed with -e if passed while the rails server command is triggered comes into picture, see:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L62-64

```
def set_environment
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= options[:environment]
end
```

for environment option see:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L31

```
      opts.on("-e", "--environment=name", String,
              "Specifies the environment to run this server under (test/development/production).",
              "Default: development") { |v| options[:environment] = v }
```

and all this is happening before your applications `environment.rb` is executed.

Hope this helps.